# Are the following two statements about limit true or false? and why?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality

1. If $\exists a $, $b$, $\forall \varepsilon >0$, $|a-b| <\varepsilon $，then $a=b$
2. If $\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists a,b,$ $|a-b| <\varepsilon$,   then $a=b$

I know the second is true, but I don't know what's wrong with the first one and the discrepancy between them!

Comment: What do the mathematical symbols `有` and `则` stand for?

Comment: @barakmanos i'm sorry ,i will edit them at once!

Answer (score 1):

The first seems correct. 
Fix $a,b$. For any given $\epsilon$, if $|a-b|<\epsilon$, then $a=b$.
You are given two numbers and you are told that the difference between the two numbers can be arbitrarily small, then a has be equal to b. You need not write $\exists$ at the first place.

The second is wrong:
Fix $\epsilon=1$, let $a=0.5$, $b=0$. Then $|0.5-1|<1$ but $0.5\neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that also the second statement is false. Maybe you should write:
 "if $a$ and $b$ are such that $|a-b|< \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then $a=b$".

Comment: i think the second is true!

Comment: I say that it doesn't make sense, because in your statement a and b can depend on $\epsilon >0$. For example take $a=\epsilon$ and $b=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ then $|a-b|=\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$, but $a\neq b$.

Comment: You have to fix a and b before your statement: $(a,b\in\mathbb{R}:|a-b|<\epsilon,  \forall \epsilon >0))\Rightarrow a=b$.

Answer (score 0):

The notation of you formulas is not clear to me.
The syntax of the language is something like

- $\forall$ variable(predicate)
- $\exists$ variable(predicate)
- (predicate) logical_operator (predicate)
- $\lnot$ (predicate)
- ...

There are of course a lot of shortcuts like operator precedence. Another is

$\forall \varepsilon >0$ (predicate)

means

$\forall \varepsilon( (\varepsilon>0) \implies$ (predicate))

or

$\exists \varepsilon >0$ (predicate)

means

$\exists \varepsilon( (\varepsilon>0) \land$ (predicate))

But we avoid shortcuts because I don't exactly know them.

So let's investigate your sentence.

Does your first one mean
$$(\exists a (\exists b( \forall \varepsilon((\varepsilon >0)\implies (\mid a-b \mid <\varepsilon ))))) \implies (a=b)$$
I think that does not make sense. $a$ and $b$ are bounded variables on the left side and free on the right side. So it's meaning is the same as

$$(\exists x (\exists y( \forall \varepsilon((\varepsilon >0)\implies (\mid x-y \mid <\varepsilon ))))) \implies (a=b)$$
Does this make sense? What is $a$ and $b$?

Or do you mean

$$\exists a (\exists b( \forall \varepsilon((\varepsilon >0) \implies  (\mid a-b \mid <\varepsilon )) \implies (a=b)))$$
Then all variables are bound but the meaning is, there exist some special values $a$ and $b$ with this property. This is true for example $a=b=1$ (or $a=b=\text{anything else}$. But I think that is not what you want to say.
There are some other possible notation when one changes the parantheses but I think none of them is the one you want. Also you can introduce parantheses in the second expression but I think you will not get what  you want.

I think you want to say:

$$\forall a ( \forall b ( (\forall \varepsilon ((\varepsilon>0)\implies(\mid a-b \mid <\varepsilon))) \implies (a=b)))  $$

This means: If you have two arbitrary number $a$ and $b$, then if for all positive $\varepsilon$ the value $\mid a-b \mid <\varepsilon$ then $a$ and $b$ must be equal.